# Use you VPS to access some website when your ISP blocked

Tags: vps, isp

My ISP (in Vietnam) has block facebook.com
Some one tell mee to edit the /etc/hosts, for example:
153.16.15.71 www.facebook.com

But I not sure where that server com from, maybe they will stole my account info. So I hope can use my Ubuntu VPS to do the same for only me! How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really simple actually - install and configure [tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) on your VPS, set your browser to use that as a proxy. Configure the proxy to only accept requests from your ip address, ideally.

If you need it to only work for facebook, you may need to set up a pac file if you only need facebook proxied - i just used [quickproxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickproxy/) to turn it off and on as needed since i was lazy